# Strava API advice

Tags: php, html

I trying to learn how to use the Strava API.  I have read through the strava guide but im still none the wiser.  I have XAMPP installed as i thought i would need it as most guide ive seen point to PHP.  I have some basic code in html to authorise my page.

```
<a href="https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=6542&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/">
    <p align="center"><img src="images/ConnectWithStrava.png" border="0" alt="Connect With Strava">
```

It goes through to the strava authorisation page and once i click authorise i then have a blank page, in the URL of the blank page is the &code=ABC123.  Im not sure what im supposed to do next?

Do I need to create a PHP to get the code from the blank page to exchange for a token? I have been looking on Google and everything points towards Github but ive never used it.

Comment: You should change the title of your post.  Recommendations for tutorials fall outside the [scope of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have that code, you can exchange it for an access token.

The following is an example from the API reference, replace the values with the ones from the app you created.

```
$ curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/oauth/token \
    -F client_id=5 \
    -F client_secret=7b2946535949ae70f015d696d8ac602830ece412 \
    -F code=75e251e3ff8fff
```

This will return you a json object.  One of the properties in that object will be the access_token,  which you can then use to retrieve other data.

again, from the api reference:

```
{
  "access_token": "83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9",
  "athlete": {
    "id": 227615,
    "resource_state": 3,
    "firstname": "John",    

EXAMPLE REQUESTS
$ curl -G https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9"
```

In a real application, that blank page would have been a redirect back to your web server which would have been able to process the request by probably storing the code, then posting the exchange request and storing the access token in a database for future use.

But if you just want to play around for now and see what kind of info you can get access to, you can use the access_token in any of the examples shown in the api reference

http://strava.github.io/api/

I am not familiar with XAMPP,  but once you have an access_token all you need is a way to make http get, post, put, patch, delete requests and you should be ready to explore the api.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that part but im not sure if i need to add this code to the html under the href or seperatly as a php?

Comment: When you click the button, that currently results in a blank page, what's happening is the _strava_ sever is making a GET request to _your_ server.  Part of that request includes the query parameter code=the_code_you_need_to_exchange_for_a_token.  So if your web server is written in php, then yes you need your php code to process that request by getting the code, and then making a second request to the strava server to exchange the code for an access token.  the "curl" commands in my answer and in the api docs are meant as example requests your server will make to strava.

Comment: Different languages have different ways of creating the http requests,  but they all boil down to requests that match what is shown in the curl statements in the api doc.  Hope that helps.